# Send received messages to api

Tags: java, android

[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs3du.png)

Hello, I have designed an application that **receives messages** and **device information** as shown in the image and show the **TextView**,
But now how to get messages and device information to an example api **file.php** in the host?

For example this is my php file in host:

http://example.com/api/file.php

How i Send it?!!

Please help to me i can complete the app

*This is my* **MainActivity.java**
*codes:*

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sender);
    msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    manufacturerTxt = findViewById(R.id.DeviceName);
    modelTxt = findViewById(R.id.DeviceModel);
    versionTxt = findViewById(R.id.AndroidVersion);
    
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    String version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    String hardware = Build.HARDWARE;

    manufacturerTxt.setText(manufacturer);
    modelTxt.setText(model);
    versionTxt.setText(version);

    
    receiveFilter = new IntentFilter();
    receiveFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver();
    registerReceiver(messageReceiver, receiveFilter);
    to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
    msgInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_input);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    
    
    

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    MessageSent();

                }
                else
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},100);
                }

            }
        });




}

private void MessageSent() {
    String num=to.getText().toString().trim();
    String msg=msgInput.getText().toString().trim();
    if(!num.equals("") && !msg.equals(""))
    {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null,msg, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fill the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
}

class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); // Retrieve SMS messages
        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        }
        String address = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress(); 
        String fullMessage = "";
        for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
            fullMessage += message.getMessageBody(); 
        }
        num.setText(address);
        msg.setText(fullMessage);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode==100 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        MessageSent();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }}

}
```

}

Comment: I use retrofit for api's

Comment: Can you give a sample code?

Comment: I'll give a link for reference please check and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

To use `REST` APIs, you should use a library called `Retrofit` or `Volley`.

You can check these two libraries and get an idea as to how to send messages over a `HTTP REST API`.

Reference:

- [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley)
- [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)